# Extended Wildcard Search in a Certain Structure of Content

Tags: sql, sql-server

The content of a column contains various entrys. The structure of the contain is as follows:

- A
- A-B
- A-B-C
- Y
- W-X
- C-R-Z

I need a statement to search only for content separated by one dash, as well as a statement to search only for content separated by two dashes.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one dash:

```
Select * From table where col like '%[a-z]-[a-z]%'
```

For two dashes:

```
Select * From table where col like '%[a-z]--[a-z]%'
```